# Travelling from Vancouver to Budapest via Amsterdam (connecting flight); do we go through Dutch customs or just transit?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, ams, klm

We are flying from Vancouver YVR to Amsterdam AMS and onto Budapest BUD with KLM.  Do we go through customs in AMS or just transit the airport?

Comment: Hi and welcome. [Suggestions aren't really our thing on TSE.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

As the flight Amsterdam to Budapest is a within Schengen, you go through immigration and passport control in Schiphol, Amsterdam airport.

You will only go through customs when you leave the flight area of the airport, you will go through customs (the green and red channels where you declare what you have brought if you have something) in Budapest.

As a transit passenger who does not need to pick up luggage and check it in anew, you will not leave the flight area of Schiphol, Amsterdam Airport. 
The airport is basically divided in a few terminals but they are connected both sides of the security walls and you can always walk from one part to the other.

So you would not go through customs in the Netherlands, you do that when you arrive in Hungary.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. If he is switching from an international to a domestic flight, he might change terminals and go through customs at that point.

Comment: In Schiphol the two terminals are connected airside as well as landside and you do not need to leave the secure area to change between flights.

Comment: Then he would almost certainly go through customs no? Otherwise all domestic passengers would also have to pass through customs (or is that standard within Schengen?)

Comment: All passengers leaving the secure zone go through customs, as far as I know there is no customs for passengers who leave on a flight. But as it is my local airport, I have never changed flights there.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst you only go through customs when you leave the baggage claim area.  If the bags are checked to BUD, which they almost certainly will be, then the traveler will not need to clear customs.

Comment: Flying from Amsterdam to Barcelona, I met my friend traveling from London in baggage reclaim, then we went together through customs on the way out. Between ours the baggage of a flight from the USA was collected, those people went through the same customs area.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes, all passengers have to walk through the customs check area on their way to the exit, even if they come from a domestic flight and are in principle not subject to any restriction. The different passengers flow (Schengen/non-Schengen/domestic) typically mix before the baggage claim area. So passengers coming, say, from a domestic Paris-Toulouse flight might be under three different set of rules depending on whether they started in Paris, connected from an EU flight or came from outside the EU. But they all go through the same customs lanes.